# Unable to link my JS files to my HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a very simple html that links to a JS file. But when I open my html file on the browser (Chrome/Firefox), I'm not able to find the JS file in the dev tools. I cant figure out what I am missing.

This is my HTML file -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="hello.js" />
    </head>
</html>
```

I've also tried using the absolute path for the src. 
This is my JS file -

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

This is my file structure:
HelloWorld [hello.html, hello.js]
The two files are at the same level. I am opening it directly like so: file:///C:/HelloWorld/hello.html

It works fine when I open it like this http://localhost:55217/hello.html (running it from Visual Studio)

Any help?

Comment: Are they in different directories? I'm not sure if the absolute path would work for a script on a local fs. You might need to do something like src="/js/hello.js", assuming the js directory is located in the same directory as hello.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a closing script tag, for example:

`<script src="hello.js"></script>`